# No tag excerpt shown when using inline editor

Tags: bug, tags, inline-tag-editor

When asking, editing or tag editing, no information about the tags is supplied to the user except for the tag name in the inline editor.

Not only do they not supply any information, they can't be middle-clicked to go to the tag page!

---

Below is an example on Code Review when I'm 'tag editing' the question. This issue is also present when asking this question. And you should be able to reproduce this issue when you [edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/325627/edit) this question.

[image: Inline tag editor without tag excerpt/wiki]

<sub>Tested in: Firefox Quantum 66.0 (64 bit) - Windows 10 (17134.648)</sub>

Comment: @AnneDaunted Has my memory betrayed me? I thought this screen used to show _some_ information.

Comment: Somehow is related to responsiveness. When I opened the edit page into a new tab (to not use inline editing), the excerpts appeared correctly because that page isn't responsive. When I disabled responsiveness completely in the footer, the excerpts appear correctly in all places.

Comment: I can't reproduce this (comparable environment to yours), does the bug still appear on your end?

Comment: @Mast If you see below, I've gone on the mobile and back to the full site, which has mostly fixed this. However I have had it a couple times after 'fixing' it.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** As pointed out in the comments, this behavior doesn't seem to relate to screen resolution only. I have not been able to reproduce it yet, though, despite using a similar/same browser. Therefore I currently consider this a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and no longer by design.

In most cases the old answer should be still correct, though:

---

Unlike @Shadow Wizard says, this behavior can also occur in the main theme.

I performed some testing and found out that the type of tag completion dialog (detailed or minimal) depends on the viewport size **when the inline editor is loaded.**

The breakpoint for this seems to be around 560px.

I would not consider this a bug though. It is probably caused by the development of the responsive design <s>and therefore [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)</s>. In fact a Stack Exchange employee commented on this:

> Somehow is related to responsiveness. When I opened the edit page into a new tab (to not use inline editing), the excerpts appeared correctly because that page isn't responsive. When I disabled responsiveness completely in the footer, the excerpts appear correctly in all places. — animuson♦

Comment: Good catch, thanks. :)

Comment: So why was it doing this when my viewport was 2560x1080 and 1280x1080? (Until I went on the mobile site and back) Pretty sure _that's_ a bug, and isn't [tag:status-bydesign].

Comment: @Peilonrayz well, this looks like a bug, yes. Are you sure you can still reproduce this? Maybe it was a temporary glitch. (Wait, I have an outdated version of Firefox. I will update and then try to reproduce; hold on)

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard As I said in that comment. "Until I went on the mobile site and back", and I don't think a 'temporary glitch' lasts a couple of months consecutively, with PC restarts.

Comment: @Peilonrayz well I can't reproduce it on my computer. Can you enter this command into the browser command line (F12): `window.innerWidth` and tell me the result? I will try to make the answer less "dogmatic" in the mean time.

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard 2344, as I have a ~200px tab window on the side. And when I SS, it goes to 1062. I didn't mention this as it still makes both width roughly over twice the 'rough activation size'.

Comment: @Peilonrayz mmh, that is strange. So definitely a bug, although I can't confirm it. I will leave my answer though, as it is probably correct in most cases (whenever somebody is not experiencing this bug) and might therefore be still helpful. As you can probably see, I have added a disclaimer to note, that this is not respecting the bug. (Edit: could it be related to your device type? I don't think so, but this is the last thing I could imagine; do you see any errors in the JavaScript console?)

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard I feel these questions arn't helpful as I can't reproduce this anymore. _As I went on the mobile site and back which fixed this_. My device is listed in the question. And no I get some failed to load `<script>` being google-analytics, quantserve and scorecardresearch. I've not changed my NoScript or adblock settings since before the bug until now, after the bug.

Comment: @Peilonrayzoh oh sorry, I read your comment on the question, as if you would still be reproducing it.

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard No problem. It's happened a couple of times very rarely since, so I can't reproduce it. Unlike when I asked this question where I could 100% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the mobile theme of the site, which never had the tag excerpts as far as I know.

To see the excerpts, switch to the full site mode by clicking "full site" in the footer:

> [image]

Comment: No I'm not. However either entering it and exiting has fixed it, or it was fixed over-night.

Comment: @Peilonrayz so somehow you got the mobile theme triggered, likely a weird bug.

Comment: "which never had the tag excerpts as far as I know" Oh? That would be awful.

Comment: This problem also occurs on the full site theme when the browser was small at the moment the editor loads.